Count Duplicate Values in Power BI
I am looking to count the number of times a brand appears in a table that is affected by slicers. The picture shows the current table, and what is currently appearing using a custom measure, and the built-in summarize (count) of the brd_name column.

I want the table to look like this:

What I truly want to do is conditionally format all duplicates, but it seems to do that I need a custom count.

Cnt = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( BRAND[pIn_nbr] ), ALLSELECTED( BRAND[pIn_nbr] ) )



Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
